# How to set ggplot alpha (transparency) value for all points at once

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha

```
library(data.table)
library(ggpolot2)

numPoints <- 10000
dt <- data.table(a=rnorm(numPoints),b=rnorm(numPoints))

qplot(a,b,data=dt, geom="point", alpha=1)
qplot(a,b,data=dt, geom="point", alpha=0.1)
qplot(a,b,data=dt, geom="point", alpha=0.01)
```

Regardless of the alpha value I choose, the resulting chart seems to have the same amount of transparency.

How can I get the points to be more transparent (so that the density of the points in an area is more clearly visible)?

Comment: Just use the function `I`, e.g. `qplot(a,b,data=dt, geom="point", alpha=I(0.1))`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Because the `...` is *other aesthetics passed for each layer*, i.e. you are not setting `alpha` you are mapping it to some value which is then the same for all values. You can tell by how you also get a legend entry for `alpha` on the plot. There are two solutions:

1) Use the `I` to indicate this is a set aesthetic;

```
qplot(a,b,data=dt, geom="point", alpha=I(0.1) )
```

2) Instead use a `ggplot` and set the aesthetic in the `geom`...

```
ggplot( dt , aes( a , b ) )+
  geom_point( alpha = 0.1 )
```

[image]
Both calls produce the same result.

Comment: ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y